# Redirect subdomain to subfolder of main domain with same structure

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Please help me to create rewrite rule for `wordpress` (**.htacess**) that will do the following:

Redirect subdomain

**AAA.site.com/BBB.html to  site.com/AAA/BBB.html**

Let me explain here

- I will create a subfolder(AAA) with same name as I have
  subdomain(AAA).
- Page name remain unchanged(BBB.html)

I have more than 100+ subdomains which i want to redirect to the "folder" with same name as subdomain using WILDCARD.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is WP installed?

Comment: Why on earth you would use mod_rewrite for this? A simple [Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) would be much simpler and clearer.

Comment: @Quentin How do you make the Redirect respect the HTTP_HOST header? (ie so it only applies to one particular subdomain)

Comment: @barryhunter — By only putting it in the VHost for that subdomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\(.*\)\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/\1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You have to swap site.com to your domain in both lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite inside your .htaccess to do this.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aaa\.site\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/aaa/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: How this will help to redirect a subdomain to a Folder if I have more than one subdomains & want to redirect automatically(Not manually like you have written folder name "aaa", It should use wildcard somehow)

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.yourwebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain_folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain_folder/$1
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the selected solution, but it did not work for me. If it also didnt work for you try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com//%1/$1
```

This should work for any sub-domain, just change example.com to your website name.